# NodeJS - Service can't use mongo -

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, service

Before explaining my issue, this is my architecture :

```
1 - server is running, getting request and storing data
2 - a service - called process_runner.js - is running on a 2nd terminal
```

the point of the service is to fetch data from my database to execute some functions.

this is the service : `process_runner.js`

```
// all needed requires
/// ...
//


mongoose.connect(config.database);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error connecting to MongoDB:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  try {
    run();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log (e);
  }

});


 //...

 var run = function() {

console.log("Start processes manager");

var taken = false;
while(true) {
  console.log ("iteration")

  if (taken == false) {
    taken = true;

    console.log("go");
    // Then I want to get my capacities
    // when the call below is done, nothing appends and the loop continues

    Capacity.find({} , function(err, capacities) {
      console.log ("OK CONTINUE");
      // ...
      // next of the events
   });
 ... }...
```

(the loop has a `sleep(1)`)

this is the output :

```
Connected to MongoDB
Start processes manager
iteration
go
iteration
iteration
iteration
...
```

so, after the 'go' message I need to recevied the 'OK CONTINUE' message, and the rest of the code will execute,

but when the `Capacity.find({} , function(err, capacities) {....`
is done, nothing appends and the loop continue (nothing in the `err`)

any ideas ?

Comment: What if you remove the `while(true)` loop? Why do you need it?

Comment: the point is to allow the service tu run in the background
I will try without the loop

Comment: Just call the same function when it finished it's execution

Comment: wow, worked, thanks !

Comment: Cool, I've summarized the comments and added them as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here lies in the `while(true)` loop. 
As `Node.js` is single-threaded you're just blocking the execution loop, which doesn't allow your database call to be executed.

Simply remove the infinite loop and call the same function upon successful execution:

```
var run = function() {
  Capacity.find({} , function(err, capacities) {
    //do stuff
    return run();
  });
}
```